# Not displaying the product list in new post type categories

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor, jet-engine

I made a post type with taxonomy with jet engine. Now, when I put the post archive widget in the categories, this widget does not find the posts on the corresponding page. It seems that it cannot find the posts. It displays the following message:
It seems we can't find what you're looking for.

The problem is not from the cache and I disabled the WordPress rocket. I also saved the permalink page again. I used other widgets, but it still doesn't show the results of the category. I must say that this list works on the post type archive page and displays all the products. But it doesn't work on the categories page.
Now I don't know how to display the products on the category & subcategories page.

I use the hello elementor theme. I created a post type using Jet Engine and named it services. Then I created a taxonomy for services. so that I can categorize them. For example, I have two main categories called import and export. My goal is that when I go to the import page, it will display the products related to the import. For this, I created a page and placed the post archive widget inside it. In the condition section, I specified that this theme should be used for category pages. According to the instructions, now by going to each category, I have to view the products of that category. But I get this message.
It seems we can't find what you're looking for

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added more details to my main question

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved with a simple solution after three weeks.
I checked the route many times and everything was correct. In frustration, I deleted the post type and created it again. Fortunately, the problem went away.